# SDWebImage insane memory growth, high virtual memory? High dirty memory size. Video Attached

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management, lazy-loading

I'm having issues with a very content rich app I'm developing. I'm using SDWebImage for caching and loading images asynchronously to my UIImageViews and UIButtons where applicable. Within this app I have content feeds which are collections views of 3 columns wide of pictures loaded from a server URL.

As I scroll, memory builds up like crazy but does clear itself when it needs to as is the expected behavior of SDWebImage. However, this application is a tabbed application, so if I scroll through one feed partially, switch tabs and scroll through a feed on another tab - memory just builds and is not getting cleared.

The first issue here that I do know is that the image size are very big and being scaled down inside the app rather than being downloaded in the right size of 100x100 PX, instead they are 640x640 px. This is obviously going to be fixed as each image needs multiple sizes for various displays throughout the app, and this will lessen the speed of the growth of the VM, but I don't believe it will solve the underlying issue of memory eventually getting to the point of crashing the app while navigating through different pages.

I notice apps like Wanelo and Path and Facebook all have infinite feeds with massive amounts of content that can scroll and load indefinitely without any noticeable loss in performance of crashes, how are they doing this?

I've also included a video with annotations of me profiling the my application with the allocations template in instruments. I can read the info OK, but I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing as far as allocations / call stack / etc goes that could possibly lead me in the right direction of solving this.

Video of profiling available here: http://youtu.be/J4zici41TMs

Comment: I used this lib a few month ago. But from some reason it didn't loaded all images or loaded randomly. So I decided to go with NSOperation.

Comment: First word of advice, rip out SDWebImage and never use it again. It's seriously not hard to roll something like this on your own while getting rid of all the mechanism. I've had a fair share of issues with apps I've done maintanance on using this library and it's beyond not worth implementing.

Comment: Infinite scrolling is not hard. It's just requests with a decent server response time, a good caching and clearing cache policy... That's pretty much it

Comment: You'll probably want to look more into core data and NSCache

Comment: Interesting, what about after the fact for scroll performance? Aside from all the little quirks of SDWebImage, would it be better to use FastImageCache?

Comment: I would build my own, but being that there are a lot of other libraries from fairly reputable sources, I'd assume they'd be able to do the job. But I do understand I'd obviously be able to tailor everything specifically to my needs if built

Answer (score 5):

If you see SDWebImage is the most optimized way of loading images asynchronously. You said you are working on tab based app and at some point your app crashes.

basically SDwebImage downloads the images and keeps them in cache memory (to speed up) and saves images locally. Whenever you move from one tab to another you can clear the cache forcely. This may help you.

try the below code when ever you are switching to a different tab.

```
[[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] imageCache] clearMemory];
```

Also in order to know other caching apis you can check this. I will always prefer SDWebImage as its really good and fast. [link](http://bpoplauschi.wordpress.com/2014/03/21/ios-image-caching-sdwebimage-vs-fastimage/).

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)